# Windows+Selenium+Chrome=unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, log4j

I'm having issue for few days now. So I uninstalled Chrome 54 and installed to 53. Didn't work.

example:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\blabla\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");

```
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.guru99.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='java_technologies']/li[3]/a")).click();
```

outputs:

....
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
.....

also problems with TestNG (i don't use log4j at all and never had to before )
outputs:

Starting ChromeDriver bla bla (.........) on port bla bla
Only local connections are allowed.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

So anybody having this kind of issue or it's just me ))))???

Comment: Your question seems to be ambiguous. In one place, you are getting WebDriver exception saying - can't find chrome binary. In another place, it's starting with some port i.e. your chrome driver is getting initialized!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may not have to do with Chrome Driver. Just add the location of your log4j.properties or log4j.xml file to the Classpath in Eclipse.

Open your project, click on the "Run" menu at the top of Eclipse and follow below steps:

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath (tab) -> User Entries -> Advanced (button on the right) -> Add Folders -> Select the path with your log4j.properties file -> Apply -> Run

Comment: Thanks @P. Bill ,  now i have no more log4j.properties issue. But i still have problem with launching chrome: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary ((((((((((( i thought it maybe cuz of Chrome was up to date, and at the start of having this issue i installed Chrome 53. didn't really help(((

Comment: Please download and try with another version of chrome driver 
from below link:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: thank u soo much, Its been awhile that i came back to this website. I remember that after few weeks it started working fine again)) I think Chrome was updating at that time